# Problem including patterns with polynomials; Functions that are inverses of itself.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $p(x)$ be the second degree polynomial such that $p(1) = 1$, $p(2) = 3$, and $p(3) = 2$. Then $p(p(x)) = x$ has four real solutions, one of which is not an integer. The solution that is not an integer can be expressed in the form $m/n$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m + n$.

Thank you for viewing this, 
I have been having trouble actually finding an equation simple enough to solve.  I have noticed that $p(p(x)) = x$ means that the function is its inverse, but cannot apply this to the problem.  Is it possible for anyone to help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think what is meant is that the polynomial $p(p(x))-x$ which is degree 4 has four roots, one of which blah blah blah. This doesn't mean $p(x)$ is its own inverse! It means only for 4 specific $x$, we have $p(p(x))=x$, and you want to find those $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)=ax^2 +bx +c $, then solve system of equation

$$p(1)=a+b+c=1$$ 
$$p(2)=4a+2b+c=3$$ 
$$p(3)=9a+3b+c=2$$

$a=-3/2$,
$b=13/2$,
$c=-4$.

$$p(x)=(-3/2)x^2 +(13/2) x -4$$
$$p(p(x))=(-3/2)(p(x))^2 +(13/2)(p(x)) -4$$
Then solve $p(p(x))-x=0$, you get (try rational root theorem if you don't have calculator)
$$p(p(x))-x=(-9/8)(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)(3x-8)$$
Therefore, m+n= $3+8=11$.

I can think of few different ways to attempt the problem, mainly from a numerical or a linear regression stand point. But this would work by brute force.

Comment: I personally recommend plugging in $x=1$, $x=2$ and $x=3$ into $p(p(x))-x$. They usually give you well behaved question. Trying your luck/ guessing is not a bad idea. It would be so much easier if you try.